# How to return an object reference from a function in C++ and how to call the function from the client side?

Tags: c++, reference

I am implementing a member function called CurrentUser. It will take a username as parameter and return the User instance object which matches the given username. Below is the code

```
User& UserDB::currentUser(string username){
      // userlists is a instance member which is list of user objects
  for(list<User>::iterator i = userlists.begin(); i != userlists.end(); ++i)
 {  
    if(*i.getName().compare(username)==0){
          return *i;
    }
 }
 return null;
}
```

Not sure if it is the correct way to do so. Correct me if it is wrong. Thanks!

Update:
hey guys thanks for your advice, i figure out a way to do so by returning a User pointer. Here is the code.

```
User* UserDB::currentUser(string username){
for(list<User>::iterator i = userlists.begin(); i != userlists.end(); ++i)
{     
    if(i->getName().compare(username)==0){
        return i;
    }
}
return null;
}
```

Comment: Also how to call the function outside from the client side? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to use a `return` statement?

Comment: Can you check my code above? not sure if it will return the reference or not.

Comment: You cannot have null references, so `return null` will not work. You have to find another way of reporting errors. Also `*i.getName()` is wrong, use `i->getName()`.

Comment: But the function require a User reference, what else should i return? Also how to call the function from the client side. Assume we declare a UserDB obejct userdb, is "User& usr = userdb.currentUser("Mike") the correct syntax? Thanks!

Comment: If the loop finishes, you might `throw` an exception.

Comment: Is this a homework? Is there an explicit requirement to return a reference?

Comment: Thanks for your help! it is not an explicit requirement to return a reference so i just return a pointer instead. I just start learning C++ so i am kind of afraid to use pointer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are a couple of ways to do this cleanly.

You can of course return a pointer, but that will be surprising to people as it is more normal to return a reference or an object. pointers present object consumers with a number of problems, e.g.:

- what should I conclude if it's null?
- should I delete it?

and so on.

Returning a reference to something or a something removes these ambiguities.

Having said that, references cannot be empty, so the function must return something. If it does not find the item it's looking for, it must indicate that to the caller. One way is an exception (i.e. it was logically incorrect to ask for that item). However, if the item not being there is a normal occurrence, then you don't want to force your consumers to handle exceptions - that's bad form too.

So the answer is to return an object that encapsulates an optional reference.

A good example of this is `boost::optional<User&>` but if you don't want to include boost it's fairly simple to roll your own:

```
struct optional_user
{
  using element_type = User;
  using reference_type = element_type&;

  optional_user() : _p(nullptr) {}

  optional_user(reference_type r)
  : _p(std::addressof(r))
  {}

  bool valid() const { return bool(_p); }

  // compares to true if the user is present, false otherwise
  operator bool() const { return valid(); }

  reference_type value() const { 
    assert(_p);
    return *_p;
  }

  // can be used anywhere a User& is required
  operator reference_type () const { 
    return value();
  }

private:
  element_type* _p = nullptr;  
};
```

now your function becomes:

```
optional_user UserDB::currentUser(string username)
{
  typedef list<User>::iterator Iter;
  for(Iter i = userlists.begin(); i != userlists.end(); ++i)
  {  
    if(i->getName().compare(username)==0)
    {
      return optional_user(*i);
    }
  }
  // return an indicator that the user is not present
  return optional_user();
}
```

and your call site becomes:

```
optional_user = users.currentUser("bob");
if (optional_user) {
  do_something_with(optional_user /* .value() */);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *specifically* return a reference, the item you are referring to must have a lifetime after execution leaves the function.

There are several alternatives:

1. static local variable in function
2. using dynamic memory
3. variable declared outside function
4. Pass by non-const reference

Here is an example of #1:

```
const std::string& Get_Model_Name(void)
{
  static const std::string model_name = "Accord";
  return model_name;
}
```

Other alternatives are to return a variable by value (copy). This doesn't use references.  A copy is returned.
For example:

```
std::string Get_Manufacturer_Name(void)
{
  return std::string("Honda");
}
```

You may also consider passing by parameter and modifying the parameter:

```
void Get_Lunch_Special_Name(std::string& entree_name)
{
  entree_name = std::string("Beef Wellington");
}
```